# load js setTimeout from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timeout

Using asp.net if I want to call a JS function from code behind I can use a ScriptManager...

```
string saveSuccessScript = "loadPopUp('Saved');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), key, saveSuccessScript, true);
```

But what if I want to call the setTimeout js function

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')
                    }, 3000);
```

which doesnt have a name. Ive given it one and tried to call it...

```
setTimeout(function timeO() {
        $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')
    }, 3000);

string saveSuccessScript = "timeO();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), key, saveSuccessScript, true);
```

this didnt work...any idea as to what I am doing wrong. ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly asp.net processes this, but since you mentioned that you need to give the function some name, this could work.

```
function myTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')
    }, 3000);
}
```

Then `saveSuccessScript` will be

```
string saveSuccessScript = "myTimeout();";
```

Comment: thanks iv tried this but it doesnt work, doesnt flag any errors in console

Comment: What if you try `saveSuccessScript = "test();";`, then make the `test` be `function test() { alert("ok"); }`. Do you get the alert?